# Handling received messages iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sms, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have got a proj work, which works in this way...
An app which connects two guys, I'm able to send a message and the other one receives it in his message inbox. Can't there be done something such that, the sent message can be read inside my application?
I have found out some ways, like using push notifications, using sqlite. Kindly suggest me which one works out well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will choose push notification to implement. But in this implementation lot of server side code has to be implemented. So my suggestion is to go through the docs and check that all your requirements are fulfilled.

For more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 and http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

The above URLs have the implementation code and profiling. The below one will give you a proper understanding of push notification.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html.